# How do I parse a whole 2-3 tree?

Tags: c, tree, 2-3-tree

I have a 2-3 tree with the following node structure:

```
struct node
{
    int value1, value2;
    node *parent, *left, *right, *middle;
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to parse the whole tree. I know how we search for it because you simply go to the right path. But how to I get to check all the nodes in the tree?

Comment: Do you mean you want to *walk* the tree?

Comment: Yes. Get through all the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is pseudocode, that might help:

```
   void ParseNode(node *n)
   {
        OperationToParseCurrentNode();

        if(n->left)
           ParseNode(n->left);
        if(n->middle)
           ParseNode(n->middle);
        if(n->right)
           ParseNode(n->right);
   }
```

This will traverse all nodes if you input the root node.